# why Yii sending data in html encoded form in mysql?

Tags: yii, html-encode

While filling form I am writing &.
But in db it is stored as `&amp;`.

My table has charset as utf-8
Any way to stop this html encoding ? I am using this data in api for android app which in turn showing & itself.

Comment: Show your controller and model code.

Answer (score 0):

It's true behavior (for security reasons), you can decode characters on your middle-ware API application for use on correct case. In special, if you use yii as your API framework, you can use [yii\helpers\Html::decode](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#decode%28%29-detail) or naive php [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) function for decode characters.